# transactionReceipt property: can't find it anymore?

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, in-app-purchase

NOTE: I'm developing for Mac, not iOS!

```
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppProIdentifier])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt     forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

I get this error from the compiler:

```
error: property 'transactionReceipt' not found on object of type 'SKPaymentTransaction *'; did you mean 'transactionDate'? [3]
```

Also, I can't find the `transactionReceipt` property in the [reference for the `SKPaymentTransaction` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008256)! (Even though this page contains some references to "receipts", there's not a transactionReceipt property).

But [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html) says it is supposed to exist!

> A successful transaction includes a transactionIdentifier property and a transactionReceipt property that record the details of the processed payment. Your application is not required to do anything with this information. You may wish to record this information to establish an audit trail for the transaction. If your application uses a server to deliver content, the receipt can be sent to your server and validated by the App Store.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I class-dumped StoreKit to find out if this method was present and it is. Here is the header:

```
@interface SKPaymentTransaction : NSObject
{
    id _internal;
}

- (id)init;
- (id)initWithDictionary:(id)arg1;
- (id)initWithPayment:(id)arg1;
- (void)dealloc;
@property(readonly) NSError *error;
@property(readonly) SKPaymentTransaction *originalTransaction;
@property(readonly) SKPayment *payment;
@property(readonly) NSDate *transactionDate;
@property(readonly) NSString *transactionIdentifier;
- (id)transactionReceipt;
@property(readonly) long long transactionState;
- (BOOL)canMergeWithTransaction:(id)arg1;
- (id)matchingIdentifier;
- (BOOL)mergeWithTransaction:(id)arg1;
- (id)_transactionIdentifier;

@end
```

You can use this method with [transaction transactionReceipt] (and get a warning). Apple may or may not consider this use of a private method and reject your application; but, for testing purposes, it is there.

Comment: I could define a category to avoid the warning.
But isn't this "use of private APIs"? I'm seriously worried my app could get rejected because of this...
Maybe I should contact Apple directly? Like fill a bug report?

Comment: I ended up filling a bug report to Apple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The property is private and returns an empty string on OS X.

As stated in Apple's docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1

> "On iOS, this is the value of the transaction's transactionReceipt
>   property. On OS X, this is the entire contents of the receipt file
>   inside the application bundle. Encode the receipt data using base64
>   encoding."

To get the receipt, use:

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]]`

An example of this working for both iOS and OS X to get the receipt and sending it to a server for verification (with a macro set for the OS X build):

```
    NSData *tr  ;
#ifdef OSX
    tr = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]] ;
#else
    tr = [transaction transactionReceipt];
#endif

    NSString *jsonObjectString = [[self encode:(uint8_t *)[tr bytes] length:[tr length]] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *completeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://ssl.myserver.com/verify.php?%@", jsonObjectString];
    NSURL *urlForValidation = [NSURL URLWithString:completeString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *validationRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlForValidation];
    [validationRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:validationRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Be careful where verifying, the json object for OS X and iOS receipts are different so you'll likely need separate server side code for validation.

Update: Adding function to encode receipt for posting:

```
+ (NSString *)encode:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length {
    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t *output = (uint8_t *)data.mutableBytes;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[index + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's official 10.7 documentation of [SKPaymentTransaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008256), there is no transactionReceipt property.

Comment: As I stated above, I am aware of this. BUT in the In App Purchase documentation there are clear references to the property...